# Is it ok to store required tools in artifacts

Tags: c#, java, .net, deployment, msbuild

I am working on automating deployment of the application on various environments. I am creating a zip file that stores binaries, configuration files for different environments and tools such as psexec, mscommunitytasks, etc. to deploy the application anywhere using that file. But I would like to know if it is ok to save mscommunitytasks and other tools that may be required down the line as an application's artifact.

Comment: Side note: some tools may not be ok to be redistributed as part of your own package due to licensing. As it is unlikely your concern leaving it only as comment.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, thats a great point. All our tools are open source so it should not be any problem.

Comment: I do this.  I usually put the "extras" in a seperate zip file sitting next to the "pure artifacts".  Why?  Well one "extra" I have is 60MB.  So I don't want to force that download everytime.  Its a gray area of course.  But the goal of the final artifact is to have everything you need to deploy...so in that essence, what you are doing makes sense.  PS  I also zip up the .config files seperately?  Why?  Usually .config setup is a one time thing, thus I avoid accidental overwrites......but the full set of config files are there just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sort of depends on your artifact definition. Allow me to give you an example.

You have a project X which has dependencies to projects A and B. In order to package it for a release package, you also need tools 1 and 2.

So now what you have is an artifact A and an artifact B. Both contain nothing.

You also have an artifact X, which contains A and B, but nothing else.

And you have an artifact which describes a proper release for X. It contains X, therefore it also contains A and B, but it also contains 1 and 2, which is necessary.

All of that is completely fine. Just make sure that the artifact with the packaging (i.e. including 1 and 2) and the one without the packaging are separate artifacts.

Comment: I ended up zipping all required binaries and files.